save xmm registers in windows kernel
I am working on a Windows kernel-mode driver and needed to perform floating-point operations using the xmm registers (xmm0, xmm1, and xmm2)
To avoid interfering with the kernel or other drivers state, I devised a method to save these registers states before the operations and restore them afterward. Below is my approach, and I would like feedback on whether it is correct and optimal
    ; Save the flags register
    pushfq

    ; Align stack to 16-byte boundary and allocate extra space for XMM registers
    sub rsp, 30h            ; 48 bytes (30h) for 3 XMM registers

    ; Save XMM registers
    movaps xmmword ptr [rsp+00h], xmm0
    movaps xmmword ptr [rsp+10h], xmm1
    movaps xmmword ptr [rsp+20h], xmm2

    ; Perform the floating-point operation
    xorps xmm0, xmm0
    cvtsi2sd xmm0, r8
    xorps xmm2, xmm2
    cvtsi2sd xmm2, r9
    xorps xmm1, xmm1
    cvtsi2sd xmm1, r10
    divsd xmm2, xmm1
    addsd xmm0, xmm2

    ; Restore XMM registers
    movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsp+00h]
    movaps xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsp+10h]
    movaps xmm2, xmmword ptr [rsp+20h]
    add rsp, 30h            ; Undo the sub rsp, 30h

    ; Restore the flags register
    popfq


Is xmm a processor register or an operating system variable?  Windows can be run on various processors.  I don't remember seeing xmm for ARM processors.

The xmm registers are indeed processor registers, not operating system variables

Microsoft recommends using dedicated helper functions to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/floating-point-support-for-64-bit-drivers (as well as wrapping your XMM-using portion of code in try-finally block). Your approach is probably more optimal, and maybe correct depending on the code; however, MS-recommended approach should be more reliable.
